# Angular default route always preloaded

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

I have two routes :

- home [ '' ]
- about [ 'about' ]

When I go to /about directly with my browser, I've notice 2 things :

- my home module is preloaded (whereas I've requested /about)
- the URL is rewritted like this : /about -> / -> /about

**app-routing.module.t**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', loadChildren: () => import('./routes/home/home.module').then(m => m.RoutesHomeModule) },
  { path: 'about', loadChildren: () => import('./routes/about/about.module').then(m => m.RoutesAboutModule) },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { relativeLinkResolution: 'legacy' }) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NavigationStart, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.less'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
        // outputs "/about" but NEVER "/"
        console.log(event.url);
      }
    });
  }

}
```

Angular : 13.0.2
Chrome : 96.0.4664.55
OS : MacOS 12.0.1

Comment: What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: I've made a mistake while typing my example, the behaviour I've described is the same without the "data: { preload: true }" in my home route

Answer (score 0):

To skip the preload of the home module you can update the route array as follow.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', loadChildren: () => import('./routes/home/home.module').then(m => m.RoutesHomeModule)},
  { path: 'about', loadChildren: () => import('./routes/about/about.module').then(m => m.RoutesAboutModule) },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

This may restrict preloading.

You can specify as `path: 'home'` instead of `path: ''`.

Comment: What changes have you made ?

Comment: Updated my answer @Ziad

Comment: The home module is not preloaded anymore but I still have the URL rewritting : /about -> / -> /about

Comment: So when you give `/about` it is redirecting to` /`  ?

Comment: Yes then it goes back to /about

Comment: Check your code with your component or auth.guard, any redirection logic had made.
Your routes seems to be good.

Comment: Is it working @Ziad ?